# How to hide a DIV if title contain stop word

Tags: php, wordpress, html, hide

I want to hide a div from a Wordpress theme, when a stop word appear in the post title.

```
<?php if (in_category('10')) { ?>
<div id="adsense-top">the adsense code</div>
<?php }else { ?>
<?php } ?>
+
<div id="adsense-bottom">the adsense code</div> - this is manually inserted
```

Basically, I need to remove the two divs from the post when the certain word is present in the title.

Comment: are you open to use `Javascript` or `jQuery`?

Comment: My .php knowledge is very limited. I don't know how to use Javascript and jQuery. :( However, if you have a simple solution based on these languages, I can test it on my site. Thank you!

Comment: `title` you referred is webpage title right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to acheive this in **`Javascript`**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var title = document.title;         //title of the page is returned
   if(title.indexOf('stop') !== -1) {  //If not found, it will return -1
     document.getElementById('adsense-bottom').style.display = 'none';
   }
</script>
```

But in `php`, you need to do like

```
<?php if (in_category('10')) { ?>
<div id="adsense-top">the adsense code</div>
<?php }else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var title = document.title;         
       if(title.indexOf('stop') !== -1) {  
         document.getElementById('adsense-bottom').style.display = 'none';
       }
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope like this you need to add.  I'm not sure this is the right place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code is not working. :( However, I believe this is not a good solution for me because the Adsense code will still be present on the page (but hidden). Am I wrong?

Comment: Hey, I just showed a simple example.  I can't test it here.  But JS is the only way to do this.  Use the respective tag's id that you want to hide.  `document.getElementById('your id')`  put the id you want to hide.

Comment: You have to make it fit to your code.  what are the divs you want to hide?  where you need to put the condition? in if or else?

Comment: I've modified the code to fit into the theme. `<?php if (in_category('10')) { ?>
<div id="rightad-top">the code is here</div>
<?php }else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var title = document.title;         
       if(title.indexOf('root') !== -1) {  
         document.getElementById('rightad-top').style.display = 'none';
       }
    </script>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: Solved:
'function filtrutitlu($titlu){
$filtru = array("root"); //cuvinte "interzise"
$cuvinte = explode(" ", $titlu);
foreach($cuvinte as $key){
if(in_array($key,$filtru))
{
    return 1;
}
}
}'

Comment: `<?php 
if(filtrutitlu(get_the_title($post->ID))==1){
    echo '';
}else{
if (in_category('10')) { 

?>
<div id="rightad-top">code here</div>
<?php }else { ?>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: @CataNic Oh you got it working, glad to here.  Thanks for sharing it :)